# Deriving a plane equation by matrix method

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

The problem is:

> The points $(2,-1,-2)$, $(1,3,12)$, and $(4,2,3)$ lie on a unique plane. Where does this plane cross the $z$-axis?

I can easily solve this problem by calculus and cross product: the equation of a plane is
$$-22x+33x-11z=-55.$$
Hence, this plane crosses the $z$-axis at $z=5$.
However, the problem requires to be sold by the system of linear equations transformed into matrix.
Even vectors have not been introduces yet. Just a matrix in echelon form and a back substitution.
Hence, when I am writing three equations:
$$2a-b-2c=d$$
$$a+3b+12c=d$$
$$4a+2b+3c=d$$ I end up with 4 variables to find.
What am I missing? Is there one more linear equation possible to add?

Comment: as long as the plane doesn't pass thru the origin you can just put $d=1$ so all the unknown coefficients are scaled accordingly

Comment: Thank you greatly! It also helped me to understand the difference between $y=mx+b$ and $Ax+By=C$.

Comment: One trick to deal with the case $Ax + By =C$ is to create an extra variable that equals one. So if we set $z=1$ and add that to our equations we can write it as $Ax+By+Cz=0$ which is linear rather than affine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Gaussian elimination,

$$\begin{cases}2a-b-2c=d,\\
a+3b+12c=d,\\
4a+2b+3c=d\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}\dfrac72b+13c=\dfrac d2,\\
4b+7c=-d\end{cases}$$

$$-\frac{55}2c=-\frac{11}2d$$ and the requested point satisfies

$$a\,0+b\,0+c\,z=d.$$

So $z=5.$